# vba error 438 but object class does contain sub

Tags: class, vba, object, runtime

I am writing code which is supposed to read in data from an Excel worksheet, save it as strings into variables contained in an object of a class which I have defined and then add this object to an object tree of a class which I have also defined.

```
Dim ProdTreeMain As New CProdTree
Dim nR As Range
Dim nnR As Range
Set nR = oXS.Range("A1")
Set nnR = oXS.Range("A1")
dim r as integer
r = 1

Do While Not (nR.Text = "" And nnR.Text = "")
    If CONDITION IS TRUE:

        Dim currProd As New CProduct

        ProdTreeMain.addProduct (currProd) '<-- error 438 "Object doesn't support property or method

    End If
    r = r + 1
    Set nR = oXS.Range("A" & CStr(r + 1))
    Set nR = oXS.Range("A" & CStr(r + 2))

Loop
```

The class CProdTree contains a sub "addProduct" which takes an input object of class CProduct by reference.

`Public Sub addProduct(ByRef Prod As CProduct)`

What the hell is going on? The class is defined, the sub correct, the variable type being passed to the sub is of the correct class and yet I get this error ... :/

Comment: You need to drop the parentheses around the argument. [Here's](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/) my favorite explanation.

Comment: @Doug: you should make that an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to drop the parentheses around the argument. My favorite explanation is this [Daily Dose of Excel post](http://dailydoseofexcel.com/archives/2012/05/01/quick-vba-tip-parentheses/).

This line:

```
ProdTreeMain.addProduct (currProd)
```

becomes:

```
ProdTreeMain.addProduct currProd
```

Comment: @MitchWheat, thanks for fleshing out my answer. It was a little sparse!

Comment: @Doug Glancy and Mitch Wheat
I tried that before but I get the same error :/

Comment: I'm sorry to hear that. I don't have any other ideas.

Comment: Error was not in this part of the code, but the parentheses were also another problem, thank you